# R HTML parsing for exact match

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I need to parse a HTML webpage for an exact match. Say my webpage contains the below tags and I'm only interested in scraping values associated with class = "revision-gradient" so that only the first tag is returned and not anything else, how do I go about it?

```
 <span class="revision-gradient">90</span>
 <span class="revision-gradient not_shadowed">75</span>
 <span class="revision-gradient shadowed">85</span>
 <span class="revision-gradient blurred">60</span>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please also provide links from where you want to scrape the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the first tag is returned"? Could you show the expect outcome?